# Unable to initialize linphone library in react native app

Tags: android, react-native, linphone, linphone-sdk

I am trying to build an voip application using react native and linphone    library.
I am trying to use linphone  android .so library and bridge it to react native. Bridgeging is working fine however, the App gets crashed when i try initialising the linphone library using below code. The same code and integration works fine in an native application.

```
linphoneCore = Factory.instance().createCore(linphoneConfigFile, linphoneFactoryConfigFile, appContext);
```

Crash details:

```
021-03-29 15:42:16.506 25350-25350/? I/crash_dump64: performing dump of process 25219 (target tid = 25301)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.540 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2021-03-29 15:42:16.540 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Nokia/TA-1021_00A0/PLE:9/PKQ1.181105.001/00A0_6_19B:user/release-keys'
2021-03-29 15:42:16.540 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2021-03-29 15:42:16.540 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2021-03-29 15:42:16.541 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG: pid: 25219, tid: 25301, name: mqt_native_modu  >>> com.vimolive.vimo <<<
2021-03-29 15:42:16.541 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
2021-03-29 15:42:16.541 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000000000062d5  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000000000000008
2021-03-29 15:42:16.541 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     x4  fefeff1b98bc9b0a  x5  fefeff1b98bc9b0a  x6  fefeff1b98bc9b0a  x7  7f7f7f7fffffff7f
2021-03-29 15:42:16.541 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     x8  0000000000000083  x9  0000007c63bb2230  x10 fffffff87ffffbdf  x11 0874a2021a1fc1fd
2021-03-29 15:42:16.541 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     x12 0874a2021a1fc1fd  x13 fffffff87ffffbdf  x14 ffffffffffffffff  x15 0874a2021a1fc1fd
2021-03-29 15:42:16.541 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     x16 0000007c63bef2b8  x17 0000007c63b11078  x18 0000007c63bf855c  x19 0000000000006283
2021-03-29 15:42:16.541 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     x20 00000000000062d5  x21 0000000000000083  x22 00000072ed6b9578  x23 0000007bc27e9588
2021-03-29 15:42:16.541 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     x24 0000000000000000  x25 0000007bc27e9588  x26 0000000000001002  x27 0000007bc27e9588
2021-03-29 15:42:16.541 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     x28 00000072edfde838  x29 0000007bc27e4110
2021-03-29 15:42:16.541 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     sp  0000007bc27e40d0  lr  0000007c63b02150  pc  0000007c63b0217c
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000002217c  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+124)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00000000000be9b8  /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/lib/arm64/libc++_shared.so (_Unwind_SetGR+16)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00000000000bac48  /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/lib/arm64/libc++_shared.so (__gxx_personality_v0+384)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000000000003cce8  /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/lib/arm64/libjscexecutor.so
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 000000000003d00c  /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/lib/arm64/libjscexecutor.so (_Unwind_RaiseException+252)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00000000000b7a78  /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/lib/arm64/libfbjni.so (__cxa_throw+112)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0000000000069d04  /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/lib/arm64/libc++_shared.so (std::__ndk1::locale::use_facet(std::__ndk1::locale::id&) const+216)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 00000000005244c4  /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/lib/arm64/liblinphone.so (_ZNSt6__ndk124__put_character_sequenceIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIT_T0_EES7_PKS4_m+160)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 000000000063a844  /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/lib/arm64/liblinphone.so (LinphonePrivate::Sal::appendStackStringToUserAgent()+252)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 000000000063a5e4  /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/lib/arm64/liblinphone.so (LinphonePrivate::Sal::Sal(_MSFactory*)+260)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00000000006ff52c  /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/lib/arm64/liblinphone.so (linphone_core_init(_LinphoneCore*, _LinphoneCoreCbs*, _LpConfig*, void*, void*, unsigned char)+212)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 0000000000700234  /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/lib/arm64/liblinphone.so (_linphone_core_new_with_config+156)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 00000000006f2acc  /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/lib/arm64/liblinphone.so (_linphone_factory_create_core(_LinphoneFactory const*, _LinphoneCoreCbs*, char const*, char const*, void*, void*, unsigned char)+88)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 0000000000764470  /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/lib/arm64/liblinphone.so (Java_org_linphone_core_FactoryImpl_createCore3+168)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 00000000005661e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+144)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 000000000055d188  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 00000000000cf740  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 00000000002823b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+344)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 000000000027d478  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<true, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+752)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.793 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 000000000052effc  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirectRange+244)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #20 pc 000000000054fc14  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+15252)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #21 pc 0000000000283d72  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes3.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/base.apk!classes3.dex (deleted) (org.linphone.core.FactoryImpl.createCore+14)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #22 pc 0000000000255e68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2415914650+496)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #23 pc 000000000025b9e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #24 pc 000000000027c350  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #25 pc 000000000052c488  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+584)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #26 pc 000000000054f814  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #27 pc 000000000018b176  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes3.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/base.apk!classes3.dex (deleted) (com.vimo.sipmno.SipManager.initSipLibrary+286)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #28 pc 0000000000255e68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2415914650+496)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #29 pc 000000000025b9e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #30 pc 000000000027c350  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #31 pc 000000000052c488  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+584)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #32 pc 000000000054f814  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #33 pc 000000000003999a  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/base.apk (deleted) (bridge.sip.nativeinterface.sip.SipHandler.startSipWithConfiguration+758)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #34 pc 0000000000255e68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2415914650+496)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #35 pc 000000000025b9e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #36 pc 000000000027c350  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #37 pc 000000000052c488  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+584)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #38 pc 000000000054f814  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #39 pc 00000000002ef69a  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes2.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/base.apk!classes2.dex (deleted) (bridge.sip.SIPModule.startSipWithConfiguration+10)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #40 pc 0000000000255e68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2415914650+496)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #41 pc 000000000051cbc8  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1032)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #42 pc 00000000005662fc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #43 pc 000000000055d188  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #44 pc 00000000000cf740  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.794 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #45 pc 0000000000463460  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #46 pc 0000000000464eb8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned long)+1440)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #47 pc 00000000003f4458  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+48)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #48 pc 000000000011e6d4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-oj.oat (offset 0x114000) (java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal [DEDUPED]+180)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #49 pc 00000000000204b8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke+1480)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #50 pc 0000000000003f24  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke+212)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #51 pc 000000000055d188  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #52 pc 00000000000cf740  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #53 pc 0000000000463460  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #54 pc 00000000004647f8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+432)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #55 pc 0000000000343528  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+648)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #56 pc 0000000000100304  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallMethodV(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+2372)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #57 pc 00000000000ed5d4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+84)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #58 pc 00000000000586dc  /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/lib/arm64/libfbjni.so (_JNIEnv::CallVoidMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+116)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #59 pc 0000000000072114  /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/lib/arm64/libreactnativejni.so
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #60 pc 0000000000068d48  /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/lib/arm64/libreactnativejni.so
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #61 pc 0000000000059a70  /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/lib/arm64/libreactnativejni.so (_ZN8facebook3jni6detail13MethodWrapperIMNS_5react15JNativeRunnableEFvvEXadL_ZNS4_3runEvEES4_vJEE8dispatchENS0_9alias_refIPNS1_8JTypeForINS0_11HybridClassIS4_NS3_8RunnableEE8JavaPartESB_vE11_javaobjectEEE+32)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #62 pc 00000000000599ec  /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/lib/arm64/libreactnativejni.so (_ZN8facebook3jni6detail15FunctionWrapperIPFvNS0_9alias_refIPNS1_8JTypeForINS0_11HybridClassINS_5react15JNativeRunnableENS6_8RunnableEE8JavaPartES8_vE11_javaobjectEEEEXadL_ZNS1_13MethodWrapperIMS7_FvvEXadL_ZNS7_3runEvEES7_vJEE8dispatchESE_EESD_vJEE4callEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+52)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #63 pc 00000000005661e0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+144)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #64 pc 00000000000250d0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.os.Handler.handleCallback+64)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #65 pc 000000000002ca0c  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+60)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #66 pc 000000000000d074  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted) (com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage+52)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #67 pc 000000000055d188  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #68 pc 00000000000cf740  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.795 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #69 pc 00000000002823b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+344)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #70 pc 000000000027c36c  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+948)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #71 pc 000000000052c488  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+584)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #72 pc 000000000054f814  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #73 pc 0000000000b19a42  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.os.Looper.loop+402)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #74 pc 0000000000255e68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2415914650+496)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #75 pc 000000000025b9e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #76 pc 000000000027c350  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #77 pc 000000000052d98c  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+204)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #78 pc 000000000054f994  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #79 pc 00000000003622f2  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes2.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.vimolive.vimo-FR8D4oReI00b7VimeJfuhw==/base.apk!classes2.dex (deleted) (com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run+74)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #80 pc 0000000000255e68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2415914650+496)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #81 pc 000000000025b9e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #82 pc 000000000027c350  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+920)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #83 pc 000000000052d400  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1392)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #84 pc 000000000054fa14  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14740)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #85 pc 00000000000ca876  /system/framework/boot-core-oj.vdex (java.lang.Thread.run+12)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #86 pc 0000000000255e68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2415914650+496)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #87 pc 000000000051cbc8  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1032)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #88 pc 00000000005662fc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #89 pc 000000000055d188  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #90 pc 00000000000cf740  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #91 pc 0000000000463460  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #92 pc 0000000000464528  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+424)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #93 pc 000000000048f898  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1120)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.796 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #94 pc 00000000000963b4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
2021-03-29 15:42:16.797 25350-25350/? A/DEBUG:     #95 pc 0000000000023afc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
2021-03-29 15:42:17.064 25219-25300/com.vimolive.vimo I/ReactNativeJS: 'Your Firebase Token is:', 'dMN-sZF4TfGZGAPMnn_SH3:APA91bFssjxMITildWZw5bS4psy0pwR5Dh23P0fRmnHMNodIh7XEKYlhlakLR1aJi1k9O9U3J5olWDzQTy13-vxBoVDTfBtaexnp1Sm_-1z7lBUHZzSt5tm6Ebo4W_-cvECg21wxCOXw'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread after hitting the same issue and was able to solve it, the key is to set the NDK version. For reference I'm using react-native 0.66.0 with LibphoneCore 5.0.32-2-gdd864933d but you may be able to get it working with others.

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
...
}
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    ...
}
```

I will publish a library with a working example at https://github.com/Woonivers/react-native-sip next week, although it's going to have a very restricted API for my particular use-case.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this but the crash does not go away. However i have found a another workaround that fixes this issue for me

Comment: @VinayRevankar people are asking for a solution. Could you please add your workaround as an answer?

Comment: Workaround -  Looks like there is an issue with initialisation of linphone library with react native. Hence to fix that,  initialise the factory instance in the main application under onCreate . Factory.instance();